# Spring Boot - Configure Elastic Search

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I would like to configure ElasticSearch

With Boot version 1.5.1 was like this, and it worked.

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.book.repository")
public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String EsHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int EsPort;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String EsClusterName;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception {

        Settings esSettings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName)
                .build();

        //https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_transport_client_versus_node_client.html
        return TransportClient.builder()
                .settings(esSettings)
                .build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), EsPort));
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }

}
```

Now I want to make it work with Spring Boot 2.0.3, and nothing works. I succeded to change the methods of the builder() and some other, but still nothing compiles.
I referred to the official documentation, but it talkes about a NodeBuilder that I can't find it anywhwere.

Reading this question [NodeBuilder not found in the ElasticSearch API application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342083/nodebuilder-not-found-in-the-elasticsearch-api-application) I see that you have now to instantiate it through the builder, but which way I pass then to the configuration?
Is there any updated example? Which documentation should I look?

Other examples don't work, e.g.,:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-elasticsearch

```
failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{VrVmfWsVQ6
```

(My server is working, the past combination of spring-boot + es was OK, and the elasticsearch server in on)

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial

Doesn't work with my pom (many classes are different from the previous version I used, to the new).

I have elastic search installed, I know is address (localhost) and port and cluster name, and I would like to connect to that.

The pom.xml

```
[...]

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<!--        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>-->
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime, for Embedded Elasticsearch, comment this if connect to external 
        elastic search server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Could you show more about your "nothing works" problem?

Comment: Using that pom and that @Configuration I can't make the ElasticSearch client work. Everything else is OK. My purpose is to make the last version of Spring Boot work with ES, in order to make simple queries.